# Android display image like Facebook/Hangout/Gallery with pinch to zooma and overlays menu

Tags: android, facebook, image, overlap, google-hangouts

I will make an activity that download an image from server and display it with trasparent overlay menus (sherlockactionbar for navigation bar, and a trasparent custom menu at the bottom of the screen).

Style like facebook image viewer or hangout viewer like. I take an hangout example:

[image: hangout example]

Other good example is the android gallery: if I tap the image the menus go away.
How can I make it?

I try to hide sherlock action bar, make 2 trasparent layout over an full screen webview that load the image: but the menu didn't overlaps the webview! This is my favorite way.

I try also open an intent in in gallery with that code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://my-server/img/1.png"), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

but it asks me with which application continue. It's possible to starts always default android gallery? This means that I can pinch to zoom with image, but I haven't custom menus!
I prefer without external libs.

Thank you very much

Comment: refer to this link http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Comment: also refer to this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_gestures.htm

Answer (score 0):

Zoomable ImageView [Click Here](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)

You can add your options above this zoomable image view and apply the logic for setting the visibility after x-time.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is to enable overlay mode for the action bar. Check out [Overlaying the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)